# Problems with Python list of lists to JSON

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

So I have a list of lists I am trying to convert to a dictionary to then convert to a JSON object.

**Example of List of Lists**

```
[
    ['service:3', 'name:Name1', 'description:What it does', 'displayname:display name of service', 'pathname:Dir path to executable', 'processid:6184', 'startname:Account\Name'],
    ['service:7', 'name:Name1', 'description:What it does', 'displayname:display name of service', 'pathname:Dir path to executable', 'processid:11188', 'startname:Account\Name'],
    ['service:4', 'name:Name1', 'description:What it does', 'displayname:display name of service', 'pathname:Dir path to executable', 'processid:8268', 'startname:Account\Name'],
    ['service:6', 'name:Name1', 'description:What it does', 'displayname:display name of service', 'pathname:Dir path to executable', 'processid:8528', 'startname:Account\Name'],
    ['service:2', 'name:Name1', 'description:What it does', 'displayname:display name of service', 'pathname:Dir path to executable', 'processid:2308', 'startname:Account\Name'],
    ['service:9', 'name:Name1', 'description:What it does', 'displayname:display name of service', 'pathname:Dir path to executable', 'processid:31380', 'startname:Account\Name'],
    ['service:1', 'name:Name1', 'description:What it does', 'displayname:display name of service', 'pathname:Dir path to executable', 'processid:2208', 'startname:Account\Name'],
    ['service:5', 'name:Name1', 'description:What it does', 'displayname:display name of service', 'pathname:Dir path to executable', 'processid:21468', 'startname:Account\Name'],
    ['service:8', 'name:Name1', 'description:What it does', 'displayname:display name of service', 'pathname:Dir path to executable', 'processid:21984', 'startname:Account\Name'],
    ['service:10', 'name:Name1', 'description:What it does', 'displayname:display name of service', 'pathname:Dir path to executable', 'processid:7560', 'startname:Account\Name']
]
```

I want to convert this to a nested dictionary with the upper tier being a server ip address.

**Example of potential dictionary**

```
{Server:Ipaddress 
    {[
    {service: 3, "name": "Name1", "description": "What it does", display"name": "display name of service", "pathname": "Dir path to executable", "processid": 6184, "startname": "Account\Name"},
    {service: 7, "name": "Name1", description: "What it does", display"name": "display name of service", "pathname": "Dir path to executable", "processid": 11188, "startname": "Account\Name"},
    {service: 4, "name": "Name1", description: "What it does", display"name": "display name of service", "pathname": "Dir path to executable", "processid": 8268, "startname": "Account\Name"},
    {service: 6, "name": "Name1", description: "What it does", display"name": "display name of service", "pathname": "Dir path to executable", "processid": 8528, "startname": "Account\Name"},
    {service: 2, "name": "Name1", description: "What it does", display"name": "display name of service", "pathname": "Dir path to executable", "processid": 2308, "startname": "Account\Name"},
    {service: 9, "name": "Name1", description: "What it does", display"name": "display name of service", "pathname": "Dir path to executable", "processid": 31380, "startname": "Account\Name"},
    {service: 1, "name": "Name1", description: "What it does", display"name": "display name of service", "pathname": "Dir path to executable", "processid": 2208, "startname": "Account\Name"},
    {service: 5, "name": "Name1", description: "What it does", display"name": "display name of service", "pathname": "Dir path to executable", "processid": 21468, "startname": "Account\Name"},
    {service: 8, "name": "Name1", description: "What it does", display"name": "display name of service", "pathname": "Dir path to executable", "processid": 21984, "startname": "Account\Name"},
    {service: 10, "name": "Name1", description: "What it does", display"name": "display name of service", "pathname": "Dir path to executable", "processid": 7560, "startname": "Account\Name"}
    ]}
}
```

I have attempted to `dict1 = dict(list1)` however, I get this `builtins.ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 7; 2 is required`

I have also attempted to

```
for item in list1:
    for i in item:
       dict1 = dict(i)
```

This of course didnt work either. `builtins.ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required`

None of the attempts I made I wasnt sure on how to include the server detail at the higher level. From what Ive read I should move the lists of lists into a dict then create a new dict with the server value and add the data from the previous dict?

Comment: Why is your list in that format to start with? Where is it coming from?

Comment: Your desired output is not valid syntax.

Comment: where original list comes from?

Comment: @jpp Apologies, please point out the format issues

Comment: @AzatIbrakov It is generated by me, by all means if there is a better way please let me know. After all iNoob

Answer (score 3):

The main issue appears to be the way you are attempting to create a list of dictionaries from a list of lists.

Notice that within each sublist you need to split each item by `":"`. `str.split` allows you to split each such instance into a list. `dict` can accept an iterable of these lists to create a dictionary. You can then perform this operation on each sublist in your outer list.

Below is a working example using a list comprehension.

```
L = [['service:3', 'name:Name1', 'description:What it does', 'displayname:display name of service', 'pathname:Dir path to executable', 'processid:6184', r'startname:Account\Name'],
     ['service:7', 'name:Name1', 'description:What it does', 'displayname:display name of service', 'pathname:Dir path to executable', 'processid:11188', r'startname:Account\Name']]

res = [dict(i.split(':') for i in item) for item in L]

print(res)

[{'description': 'What it does',
  'displayname': 'display name of service',
  'name': 'Name1',
  'pathname': 'Dir path to executable',
  'processid': '6184',
  'service': '3',
  'startname': 'Account\\Name'},
 {'description': 'What it does',
  'displayname': 'display name of service',
  'name': 'Name1',
  'pathname': 'Dir path to executable',
  'processid': '11188',
  'service': '7',
  'startname': 'Account\\Name'}]
```

Comment: Yes I can see that thanks, I intend on adding a key value pair above that of 'Server: Ip' too. Thanks for the help one im able to I will try build on the the information you have all supplied. An explination for the down vote would be appreciated too